Measuring correlation and percentage returns for data that can go both positive and negative
I am trying to measure the correlation between 2 random variables $X$ and $Y$. $X$ is current position of a stock, where $X>0$ would be long (buying) and $X<0$ would be short (selling). $Y$ is the price of the stock.
Usually to measure the correlation between 2 stocks, you calculate the percentage-returns (or log-returns) of each stock and measure the correlation $\rho(r_X, r_Y)$. But the issue in my case is the $X$ is the position which can be negative or even 0.
The issue that arises is that if the position at $t$ is $X_t=10$ and then 15 stock is shorted, $X_{t+1}=-5$, then the returns would be $$r_X=\frac{-5+10}{10}=\frac{1}{2}$$
I figured, you can use the method
$$r_X=-\frac{|-5|+|10|}{10}=-\frac{3}{2}$$
which somewhat works if the current position never reaches 0.
$$r_X=-\frac{|-5|+|0|}{0}=\text{not useful}$$
or a small number:
$$r_X=\frac{|10|+|0.001|}{0.001}=10,001$$
I am starting to think percentage change isn't even useful in this context since percentage returns is all about reference point and being at 2 then going to 4 wouldn't be the same as going from 10 to 20 (The 2nd being bigger move in the data set). And so it would be better use the difference of the position and the returns of the stock for the correlation:
$$d_{X_{t+1}} = X_{t+1} - X_t$$
$$r_{Y_{t+1}} = \frac{Y_{t+1} - Y_t}{Y_t}$$
$$\rho(d_{X_{t+1}}, r_{Y_{t+1}})$$

You appear to be confusing two different problems: do you want the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ (which is a standard, well-defined quantity) or do you want to invent some kind of generalized "percentage return" for short positions?  Could you perhaps explain why you want to compute some kind of correlation?  That might give us useful hints concerning your situation.

@whuber I am trying to  find the correlation between X and Y. Since Y are prices, it makes sense to use percentage returns, but for the positions (X), percentage returns as defined similarly to Y's pct returns does make sense. And so I thought maybe there was another way of describing percentage returns that is friendlier with negatives to measure their correlation. I have thought of a potential engineering/hacky resolution where the normalizer (what you would put in the denominator for pct returns) would be the recent rolling volume to give comparison to 2 different position movements

i.e. If company in 2020 has weekly volume of 100m, but then in 2024 it has 600m, a 5m positional change (short long) is more relevant in 2020 than it is in 2024
